# How can I get ansible 1.9 to reduce my stdout_lines into a dict?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a task like so:

```
- name: Set locale facts
  set_fact:
    locales: "{{ dict(locales, **{ item.split('=')[0]: item.split('=')[1] }) }}"
  with_items: system_locales.stdout_lines
```

But it ends up with only the last item from **stdout_lines**. Why isn't it merging and how can I make it?